# What is the duration to file international patents after filing in USPTO?

Tags: provisional

I'm also gonna file provisional patent this month. I already have a US Intent to Use Trademark. My Intent to Use application got approved in Feb 2017.

How long do I have to file international patent via WIPO?

Answer (score 1):

A PCT patent application must be filed within 12 months of the date that the provisional patent application was filed ([Paris Convention art 4(C)(1)](http://www.wipo.int/wipolex/en/treaties/text.jsp?file_id=288514#P83_6610)).

Comment: Thanks. Any idea about trademark duration?

Comment: An "intent-to-use" USPTO trademark application that has been "allowed" must be followed up with a filing of a verified "statement of use" in commerce within six months unless an extension is requested and granted (for up to 36 months from the Notice of Allowance). Otherwise the application for registration will be deemed abandoned. The registration has a 10-year duration, subject to the necessary filings and fees.

Comment: Hi Meca, Is 12 months window available for trademark too? If I file a trademark in uspto today, can I seek international protection in the next 12 months? Or its applicable only for Patents?

Comment: @user1091558 I would recommend asking a question at Law.SE about that. It'd be the best way to get a good answer.